# Webform event registration confirmation email

Tags: civievent, drupal, webform-civicrm

We are just starting to use Webform to register users for a specific event. When the confirmation email is sent, we would like to have the event information (name, date, location) in the email. Can this be done using tokens or will it have to be hard-coded? This is not anything the user submitted. It would be pulled from the event in Civi.

Comment: is this email going from webform, or from civievent?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion the email would be coming from webform. I'm going to play the dummy card here, if the user is registering for a civievent using a webform, is there a way to send them the standard civievent email instead of the webform email? We are actually trying to get the webform email to look like the civievent confirmation email.

Comment: i thought default behavious with w_c was that registering for an Event triggers the civievent receipt/confirmation - but i could be wrong (I practice lots)

Answer (score 2):

[image]I've gotten as far as event name and date (and time, optionally) by setting Title Display to "Title + Start-Date-Time" for example, and ensuring that the confirmation email that sends to registrants includes the token [submission:values]. If you want to exclude the submitters' details and just the event info, under Webform > E-mails, you can go to "Included e-mail values" and uncheck everything but "Event".

Answer (score 1):

There may also be a way to do that with webform features but you may want to have a look a the extension "[Custom Event Communication](https://docs.civicrm.org/eventmessages/en/latest/)" which allows you to define specific emails for each event.